# Ruby on Rails - Access Children Relation from has_and_belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem with this one, and I cannot find the answer anywhere on the Internet.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "region_translations"
LINE 1: ...ions"."id" = "orders_regions"."region_id" WHERE ((region_tra...
```

So I have the class Order, that has this relation:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :regions, :trough => :regions_orders
```

Then, I have this method in the rails admin section:

```
rails_admin do
    parent Booklet

    list do

      field :first_name
      field :last_name
      field :sent
      field :address
      field :state
      field :city
      field :postal_code

      field :booklets_orders
      field :regions
      field :language

      field :regions do
          searchable ({Region::Translation => :title})
          sortable({:region_translations => :title})
          filterable true
          queryable true
      end
```

Then, I see the region appearing in the possible filter, but if I try a request, I get the error mentionned above. From what I understand, it's because it is not doing a left join between the table `orders_regions.region_id` and the `region_translation`. But I am honestly not sure how to access it, the relation is properly set between `region` and `region_translation` (it works everywhere in the site), so I'm stucked there... Any clues ?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` with `through`. If you have a join model (in your case, `regions_orders`), you should simply use `has_many` with `through`, which might fix your problem. (See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: It's a many to many relationship

Comment: Yes, but the `has_and_belongs_to_many` method is for cases when you don't want a join model, so you never use the `through`option.

 When you do have a join model (like your case), you should use `has_many :regions, through: :regions_orders` in your `order` model, and `has_many :orders, through :regions_orders` in your `region` model. 

Check the link I posted in my previous comment, it explains the difference more clearly.

Comment: I agree, I removed the :through and it still does not work tho

Comment: Rather than removing the `through` (and keeping `has_and_belongs_to_many`) you should do it the other way round, if you have the `regions_orders` model as suggested. So try `has_many :regions, :trough => :regions_orders` and maybe also update your question.

Comment: I understand what you say, it does not work, it says that regions.order_id does not exsits, because it,s a many to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set this up explicitly:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions_orders
  has_many :regions, through: :regions_orders
end

class RegionsOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions_orders
  has_many :orders, through: :regions_orders
end
```

The regions_orders table is the join table and will have the order_id and region_id columns, along with any other columns you wish to put in it. These additional columns should reflect some entity that is a combination of the region and order for that row. For example, you may have an additional column called quantity, which would represent the quantity of units sold for the order in that region. So one row of your join table could look like this for order_id, region_id and quantity respectively: 22, 12, 1000. Which means that 1000 units were sold in region 12 (this is the id for the region in the regions table) for order 22 (this is the id for the order in the orders table). I don't know what you are trying to model, but I hope this helps.